# answer questions using keyborad letters as short cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Can we answer questions using keyborad letters as short cut.
In other words, if we have a Choice question like Gender and choices are Male/Female. Can this question answered by clicking on M/F or 1/2?

Html Code:

```
 <div class="">
        <strong class=""><span style="">Gander</span></strong>
        <input  type="radio" name="Gander_sq_101" value="001Male" > Male
        <input  type="radio" name="Gander_sq_101" value="002Female"> Female
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about browser api or do you want to add javascript code ?

Comment: @Vayrex I want to add JavaScript code and i'm build my question from json array,  unknown number and answer of questions

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript to handle keypress or keydown event.

```
document.onkeypress = function(e){console.log(e)};
```

Then switch e.which or e.key param and if it is needed key, execute needed functionality.

Comment: Both `keypress` and `e.which` are deprecated. `keydown` and `e.key` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do that using jquery

```js
$(document).on('keyup' , function(e){
  var MaleOrFemale = (e.which == 49 || e.which == 77)? '001Male' : (e.which == 50 || e.which == 70) ? '002Female' : '';
  $('[name="Gander_sq_101"][value="'+MaleOrFemale+'"]').prop('checked' , true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
      <strong class=""><span style="">Gander</span></strong>
      <input type="radio" name="Gander_sq_101" value="001Male" > Male
      <input  type="radio" name="Gander_sq_101" value="002Female"> Female
</div>
```

> **Note :** after click <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> you need to focus on iframe to see the result

Comment: I want to add JavaScript code and i'm build my question from json array,  unknown number and answer of questions

Comment: `e.which` is deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with jQuery:

```
$( "body" ).keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Then you need to check e.keyCode for the key you want. Here you can simply find your right keycode: http://keycode.info

Comment: Both `keypress` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated. `keydown` and `e.key` should be used instead. Also, take a look at this other similar tool: https://keyjs.dev